# Nested for loop doesnt execute as expected in node/puppeteer context

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, scope, puppeteer

I've encountered some weird behaviour in the execution of the nested for-loop on the second level of nesting on the code snippet below.
The logs I added for debugging followed this pattern:

```
i: 0
j: 0
j: 0
k: 0
j: 0
j: 0
16/121/61
k: 1
j: 0
j: 0
16/121/01
k: 2
j: 0
j: 0
16/121/02
k: 3
j: 0
j: 0
...
16/121/08
j: 1
j: 1
j: 2
j: 2
j: 3
j: 3
j: 4
j: 4
j: 5
j: 5
j: 6
j: 6
...
17/121/01
i: 1
k: 1
j: 0
j: 0
...
```

As opposed to what I would actually expect:

```
i: 0
j: 0
j: 0
k: 0
j: 0
j: 0
16/121/61
k: 1
j: 0
j: 0
16/121/01
k: 2
j: 0
j: 0
16/121/02
k: 3
j: 0
j: 0
...
16/121/08
j: 1
j: 1
k: 1
j: 1
j: 1
17/121/01
j: 1
j: 1
k: 2
j: 1
j: 1
17/121/02
j: 1
j: 1
k: 3
j: 1
j: 1
...
j: 2
j: 2
k: 0
j: 2
j: 2
```

It seems the for loop only execues part of it's scope on any iteration:

```
for (let j = 0; j < courses.length; j++) {
                    console.log('j: ' + j);
                    await page.select('#course-select', courses[j]);
                    await page.waitFor(750);
                    const groups = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#group-select option:not(:first-child)')).map(group => group.value));
                    console.log('j: ' + j);
```

Entire code-snippet:

```
module.exports = (puppeteer) => {
    return async () => {
        console.log('Timetable scraper started!');
        // remove node.js-restrictions, do not delete!!
        process.setMaxListeners(Infinity);
        const timetables = [];
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            // inject the logs of the browser into the node environment, useful for page.evaluate()
            page.on('console', (log) => console[log._type](log._text));

            await page.goto('https://www.htw-dresden.de/studium/im-studium/aktuelle-stunden-und-raumplaene');

            // fetch all possible timetableIDs
            const immatriculationYears = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#mat-select option:not(:first-child)')).map(year => year.value));
            for (let i = 0; i < immatriculationYears.length; i++) {
                console.log('i: ' + i);
                await page.select('#mat-select', immatriculationYears[i]);
                await page.waitFor(750);
                const courses = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#course-select option:not(:first-child)')).map(course => course.value));
                for (let j = 0; j < courses.length; j++) {
                    console.log('j: ' + j);
                    await page.select('#course-select', courses[j]);
                    await page.waitFor(750);
                    const groups = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#group-select option:not(:first-child)')).map(group => group.value));
                    console.log('j: ' + j);
                    for (let k = 0; k < 1; k++) { //groups.length
                        console.log('k: ' + k);
                        console.log('j: ' + j);
                        await page.select('#mat-select', await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#mat-select option').value));
                        // fill field to request current timetable by format: Year/Course/Group
                        const timetableID = `${immatriculationYears[i]}/${courses[j]}/${groups[k]}`;
                        await page.type('#study-group', timetableID);
                        // navigate to timetable-site
                        await Promise.all([
                            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
                            page.click('#select-submit')
                        ]);
                        // select compact listview of timetable
                        await Promise.all([
                            page.waitForSelector('#ui-id-4', {
                                timeout: 8000
                            }),
                            page.click('#ui-id-4'),
                        ]);
                        await page.waitFor(1000);
                        console.log('j: ' + j);
                        // fetch current timetable data
                        const timetable = await page.evaluate(timetableID => {
                            const timetableRows = document.querySelectorAll('.list-activity');
                            const table = {
                                id: timetableID,
                                activities: []
                            };
                            for (let l = 0; l < timetableRows.length; l++) {
                                table.activities.push({
                                    title: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-title').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    description: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-description').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    type: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-type').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    day: timetableRows[l].querySelector('td:not([class*="activity"])').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    rotation: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-rotation').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    start: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-start').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    end: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-end').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    location: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-location').innerHTML.trim(),
                                    staff: timetableRows[l].querySelector('.activity-staff').innerHTML.trim(),
                                });
                            }
                            return table;
                        }, timetableID);
                        timetables.push(timetable);
                        console.log(timetable.id);
                        await page.goto('https://www.htw-dresden.de/studium/im-studium/aktuelle-stunden-und-raumplaene');
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log('Timetable scraper finnished!');
            await browser.close();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Error while scraping, check for changes on the scraped site! \n ${err}`);
        } finally {
            console.log(timetables.length);
            return timetables;
        }
    }
};
```

Has anyone ever experienced such behaviour in this environment (node/puppeteer) or has any heads up for further debugging?

Edit: Added an example of what the expected log would be.

Comment: What's the expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question initially.
The expected behaviour would be to have the second loop run the entire code encapsulated in its scope, instead of just running the bit up to the beginning of the next for loop.